# Summing the lengths of lists inside a list in R

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have 2 lists inside a list in R. Each sublist contains a different number of dataframes. The data looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = letters[1:5])
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:15, y = letters[1:15])
df3 <- data.frame(x = 1:25, y = letters[1:25])
df4 <- data.frame(x = 1:6, y = letters[1:6])
df5 <- data.frame(x = 1:8, y = letters[1:8])

l1 <- list(df1, df2)
l2 <- list(df3, df4, df5)
mylist <- list(l1, l2)
```

I want to count the total number of dataframes I have in mylist (answer should be 5, as I have 5 data frames in total).

Comment: Can it be nested deeper ? if so no current solution will work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `lengths()`:

```
sum(lengths(mylist)) # 5
```

From the official documentation:

> [...] a more efficient version of sapply(x, length)

Answer (score 3):

```
library(purrr)
mylist |> map(length) |> simplify() |> sum()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
lapply(mylist,length) |> unlist() |> sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```r
sum(sapply(mylist, length))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `unlist` and use `length`.

```r
length(unlist(mylist, recursive = F))
# [1] 5
```

Forr lists of arbitrary length, one can use [`rrapply::rrapply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71970037/flatten-deeply-nested-list-of-dataframes):

```r
length(rrapply(mylist, classes = "data.frame", how = "flatten"))
# 5
```

Answer (score 1):

`length(unlist(mylist, recursive = F))` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mylist %>% flatten %>% length

#> [1] 5
```